# Django template access dictionary key

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Currently I am passing a dictionary with multiple keys from my views to django template, and the first key contains a list with all the wanted keys, and I want to have a nested loop to loop inside the first key so I can access inside the wanted keys.

```
dict = {
"list1" = ["name1", "name5"]
"name1" = []
"name2" = []
"name3" = []
"name5" = []
}
```

In this case, I only want to access dict['name1'] and dict['name5'], in Python I can do something like:

```
for name in dict['list1']:
  for l in dict[name]:
    do things
```

I want to know if I can do the same with django template inside html file

Comment: *"I only want to access dict['name1'] and dict['name5']"*. Then you should only pass to the template what it needs instead of a complex structure.

Comment: @KlausD. The above is just an example, name2,name3,name4 will be used in other occasions, but will not be called in the same way as name1 and name5

Comment: And why don't you just create a more simple and therefore more template friendly data structure? Data processing should happen in Python, not in the template.

Comment: @KlausD. So in the template, I want to have multiple select choices, with each select tag containing multiple option tags, so with the above example, I have a list containing different types of select that I want the users to choose from, and each type of select have a corresponding list of options that the type of select has. That's why I thought it would be easier if there's a way to do it in the template

Answer (score 0):

first you will get syntax error you should not use `=` you should use `:` in dictionary and add `,` after each key value pair

```
dict = {
"list1" : ["name1", "name5"],
"name1" : [],
"name2" : [],
"name3" : [],
"name5" : [],
}
```

Comment: The above code is just an example, as I am bad at explaining when it comes in plain text, so I thought it would be easier to have a visible code to demonstrate.

Comment: @LurkerDoge i understood that I am telling the rules of Python's Dictionary